# Why can't I add the the qgis.org repository public key to Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: qgis, installation, ubuntu

I'm trying to install QGIS in Ubuntu 12.04 but I can't import the public key:

```
mferreira@cibiows1:~$ gpg --recv-key 997D3880
gpg: requesting key 997D3880 from hkp server keys.gnupg.net
gpg: keyserver timed out
gpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error
```

Even if I try sudo it it gives an error message:

```
mferreira@cibiows1:~$ sudo gpg --recv-key 47765B75
[sudo] password for mferreira: 
gpg: WARNING: unsafe ownership on configuration file `/home/mferreira/.gnupg/gpg.conf'
gpg: external program calls are disabled due to unsafe options file permissions
gpg: keyserver communications error: general error
gpg: keyserver receive failed: general error
```

Does anyone I have any idea how to work around this?

Comment: See http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/unable-to-connect-to-keys-gnupg-net-838576/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you don't have access to the keyserver, likely a naming issue or a firewall blocking the connection. Check [this thread at AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60233/when-i-try-to-add-repositories-why-are-ubuntus-keyservers-timing-out).